# How to Build Multi-step Forms with Preview data fill page in drupal 8?

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-8

many days I working on drupal 8 custom form module which is the multi-step form I have complete this using SessionManagerInterface that's work fine but I want to display all data in one page before submit how can I achieve this .here I include [snapshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w40wA.jpg)

demo.routing.yml

```
demo.multistep_one:
  path: '/demo/multistep-one'
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\demo\Form\Multistep\MultistepOneForm'
    _title: 'First form'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
demo.multistep_two:
  path: '/demo/multistep-two'
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\demo\Form\Multistep\MultistepTwoForm'
    _title: 'Second form'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'ent'
```

MultistepFormBase.php

```
namespace Drupal\demo\Form\Multistep;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Session\SessionManagerInterface;
use Drupal\user\PrivateTempStoreFactory;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

abstract class MultistepFormBase extends FormBase {

  /**
   * @var \Drupal\user\PrivateTempStoreFactory
   */
  protected $tempStoreFactory;

  /**
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Session\SessionManagerInterface
   */
  private $sessionManager;

  /**
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface
   */
  private $currentUser;

  /**
   * @var \Drupal\user\PrivateTempStore
   */
  protected $store;

  /**
   * Constructs a \Drupal\demo\Form\Multistep\MultistepFormBase.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\user\PrivateTempStoreFactory $temp_store_factory
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Session\SessionManagerInterface $session_manager
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface $current_user
   */
  public function __construct(PrivateTempStoreFactory $temp_store_factory, SessionManagerInterface $session_manager, AccountInterface $current_user) {
    $this->tempStoreFactory = $temp_store_factory;
    $this->sessionManager = $session_manager;
    $this->currentUser = $current_user;

    $this->store = $this->tempStoreFactory->get('multistep_data');
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
    return new static(
      $container->get('user.private_tempstore'),
      $container->get('session_manager'),
      $container->get('current_user')
    );
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    // Start a manual session for anonymous users.
    if ($this->currentUser->isAnonymous() && !isset($_SESSION['multistep_form_holds_session'])) {
      $_SESSION['multistep_form_holds_session'] = true;
      $this->sessionManager->start();
    }

    $form = array();
    $form['actions']['#type'] = 'actions';
    $form['actions']['submit'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Submit'),
      '#button_type' => 'primary',
      '#attributes' => array(
              'class' => array(
                   'btn btn-register' 
                ),
    ),
);


    return $form;
  }
```

MultistepOneForm.php which child form

```
namespace Drupal\demo\Form\Multistep;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

class MultistepOneForm extends MultistepFormBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}.
   */
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'multistep_form_one';
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}.
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $form = parent::buildForm($form, $form_state);

    $form['fname'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => $this->t('Your name'),
      '#default_value' => $this->store->get('fname') ? $this->store->get('fname') : '',
       '#attributes' => array(
              'class' => array(
                   'form-control' 
                   ),
               ),

    );

    $form['lname'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => $this->t('Your Last Name'),
      '#default_value' => $this->store->get('lname') ? $this->store->get('lname') : '',
       '#attributes' => array(
              'class' => array(
                   'form-control' 
                   ),
               ),
    $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = $this->t('Continue');

    return $form;
  }  
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $this->store->set('fname', $form_state->getValue('fname'));
   $this->store->set('lname', $form_state->getValue('lname'));
 $form_state->setRedirect('demo.multistep_two');   
}
}
```

MultistepTwoForm.php

```
namespace Drupal\demo\Form\Multistep;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Url;

class MultistepTwoForm extends MultistepFormBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}.
   */
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'multistep_form_two';
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}.
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $form = parent::buildForm($form, $form_state);

    $form['jfname'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => $this->t('Joint Account Holder First Name'),
      '#attributes' => array(
              'class' => array(
                   'form-control' 
                   ),
               ),
     );

    $form['jlname'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => $this->t('Joint Account Holder Last Name'),
      '#attributes' => array(
              'class' => array(
                   'form-control' 
                   ),
               ),
    );
 $form['actions']['previous'] = array(
      '#type' => 'link',
      '#title' => $this->t('Previous'),
       '#url' => Url::fromRoute('demo.multistep_one'),
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
         '#attributes' => array(
              'class' => array(
                   'btn btn-register' 
                   ),
               ),

    );
 $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = $this->t('Continue');
    return $form;
  }

 public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $this->store->set('jfname', $form_state->getValue('jfname'));
    $this->store->set('jlname', $form_state->getValue('jlname'));
   // $form_state->setRedirect('demo.multistep_three');
  }
}
```

here my concern is raised How to display all data according to  my snapshot.what action needs to be taken display data. one thing is that i have 3 month experience about drupal so can't take decision what i will do? this code is example of www.sitepoint.com and I take form three and session data is display in label whether it good or not i don't know give me direction appropriate
thanks in advance

Comment: The question is large and request for implementation of specific feature without stating what the author already tried (or not) and where they are having difficulties. The topic is already well covered on-line in multiple blog posts and tutorial easy to find using obvious search keywords.

Comment: thanks, Pierre, I have completed Multistep Form But Problem Only Display All Data Single Page Before Submit.I have No idea how to do I complete?

Comment: Rework the question, provide working code (try to make it as simple as possible, remove real-world stuff to make it easier to grasp) and point out exactly what is working and what is not (or is missing). See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your setup, you are submitting the multiform in MultistepTwoForm.
Change this as follows:

- Build one more form: MultiStepPreview. This will hold your preview.
- Do Not submit the form in MultistepTwoForm but redirect the form to MultiStepPreview using `$form_state->setRedirect()`

In MultiStepPreview:

- read the keys in the store
- build a form element containing the preview (I made a html table to contain the preview)
- submit the form.

  ```
  class OverviewForm extends MultiStepFormBase {
    public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
      // get data from the store
      $your_details = $this->store->get('your_details');
      $order = $this->store->get('order_details');

      // make a HTML table containing the data in store
      $markup = '<table>'; 
      // loop through $your_details and $your_order and put them in $markup

      $form = parent::buildForm($form, $form_state);
      $form['preview'] = [
        '#markup' => $markup,
      ];
      //in my setup all the buttons are build by MultiStepFormBase  
     return $form;
    }
  ```

  }